# Unexpected behavior with ActiveRecord includes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm using the AR [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) method to execute a LEFT OUTER JOIN between objects **User** and **Building**, where a User may or may not have a Building association:

```
users = User.includes(:building).references(:buildings)
```

Since I'm using [`references`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references), any associated Building objects will be eager loaded.

My expectation was that I would then be able to iterate through the list of users, and check whether a user had a building associated with them without triggering additional queries, but I see that in fact whenever I try to access the building property of a user that doesn't have one, AR makes another SQL call to try and retrieve that building (though on subsequent tries it will just return nil).

These queries are obviously redundant as the association would have been loaded during the initial join, and seems to defeat the whole purpose of eager loading with includes/references, as now I'm looking at N times the number of queries equal to the number of empty associations.

```
users.each do | user |

  # This will trigger a new query when building is not present: 
  # SELECT  "buildings".* FROM "buildings" WHERE "buildings"."address" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["address", "123 my street"]]
  if user.building
    puts 'User has building'
  else
    puts 'User has no building' 
  end

end
```

User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building, foreign_key: 'residence_id'
end
```

Is there a way to check the presence of the users' building association without triggering extra queries?

---

ON RAILS 4.2.0 / POSTGRES

---

**UPDATE:**

Thank you @BoraMa for putting together this [test](https://gist.github.com/borama/68a8ca48728669474da95986527ed6e4). Looks like we're getting different behavior across recent Rails versions:

OUTPUT (RAILS 4.2.0):

```
User 1 has building
User 2 has building
User 3 has no building
D, [2016-05-26T11:48:38.147316 #11910] DEBUG -- :   Building Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "buildings".* FROM "buildings" WHERE "buildings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 123]]
User 4 has no building
```

OUTPUT (RAILS 4.2.6)

```
User 1 has building
User 2 has building
User 3 has no building
User 4 has no building
```

OUTPUT (RAILS 5.0.0)

```
User 1 has building
User 2 has building
User 3 has no building
User 4 has no building
```

Take aways:

- This issue was limited to "dangling foreign keys (ie the residence_id
  column is not nil but there is no corresponding building object)"
  (THANKS @FrederickCheung)
- The issue has been resolved as of Rails 4.2.6

Comment: I would expect an error similar to "ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError: Association named 'buildings' was not found on User". Can you confirm the query syntax as well as User->Building association definition?

Comment: @messanjah Personally I would expect `user.building` to return nil if the association didn't exist, and that's what happens on subsequent calls, but on the first call it always fires a SQL query.

Comment: Strange, I don't observe this behavior - my nil associations are just returning nil, without further queries. Is the code that you have given in the question indeed a minimal working example of the problem?

Comment: @BoraMa Yes the example is accurate

Comment: Which exact version of rails are you using? And which database are you using? I'm assuming Rails 4.1 w/ Postgres?

Comment: @LukeExton Rails 4.2 / Postgres

Comment: What digit comes after 4.2 in your Rails version?

Comment: Do you have "dangling" foreign keys (ie the residence_id column is not nil but there is no corresponding building object) ?

Comment: @Yarin, please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/borama/68a8ca48728669474da95986527ed6e4) with minimal runnable test. I tried this on Rails 4.2.6 with Postgres and **still see no additional queries**. Please try running this on your system and tell us if it still behaves wrongly, if not, please try to update it so that it actually does the excess queries. Perhaps also post the schema of the two tables (but I myself am not sure if it's relevant).

Comment: @FrederickCheung - Yes, the FK will always have a value, it just may not correspond with a building record

Comment: @BoraMa - Awesome, thanks for putting that together. See question update for results!

Comment: Aha! So it's indeed the 'dangling' foreign keys that @FrederickCheung commented above. Will dig more...

Comment: @BoraMa Yes combination of dangling keys and the Rails version. See latest updates. Also, please make your comments an answer so I can give you cred!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you got bit by a [bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18312) in Active Record, that was fixed in rails 4.2.3.

In the case where the column was nil Active Record already knows that it doesn't even need to try loading the associated object. The remaining cases were the ones impacted by this bug

Comment: For the win! Nice find, thanks for all your help this was killing me

Comment: Aah, too late! But you deserve it, Frederick :) Glad we all nailed this interesting bug.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a typo, please notice `building` instead of `buildings`: `User.includes(:building).references(:buildings)`

That should trigger the big query that uses the format of `AS tX_rY` for each association and table.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, but that doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since rails 4.1 there are potential clashes with how just how implicit #includes should be, see the following [open issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14657).

This code is all untested for syntax, but there would be two approaches I would try:

1/ Make the eager loading implicit

```
users = User.eager_load(:building).preload(:buildings)
```

2/ Separate out the two types of users, ones where the building is attached, meaning you don't even try and preload the building, removing the innefficiency.

```
users = User.includes(:building).where.not(residence_id: nil).references(:buildings)

users.each do | user|
     puts "User has building: #{user} #{user.building}"
end

# No additional references needed to be eager-loaded.
users = User.where(residence_id: nil)
users.each do | user |
     puts "#{User} has no building."
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. #1 did not change the results- the initial query was the same, as was the behavior when accessing missing associations. As for #2, splitting it into two separate queries would work for this limited example, but not an option in real-world applications where we would need to perform filtering/paging operations on the query as a whole